# How can I make my protractor test pass?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I created a simple protractor test for my angular app. When I click a button an input value gets set:

```
 $scope.fillForm=function(){
        console.log('fillform');
        $scope.myText='hoera';
    };
```

The e2e test expects the input to be populated with 'hoera':

```
describe('fill in form e2e test', function () {
    it('should test  form', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:63342/protractor_new/index.html');
        element(by.buttonText('go')).click().then(function () {
            var el = element(by.model('myText')).getText();
            expect(el).toEqual('hoera');
        });
    });
});
```

When I run the test with 'protractor conf' I get:

```
Expected '' to equal 'hoera'.
```

I would expect something like : expected 'hoera' to equal 'hoera'? How can I make it pass maybe there is a delay before angular sets the value? Here is a link to the code: https://github.com/dimitri-a/protractor_new

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Your `get` and `click` should be added to the `controlFlow`, so no need to have a `then` on the click. But you DO need a `then` on your `getText`. This should work...

```
describe('fill in form e2e test', function () {
    it('should test  form', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:63342/protractor_new/index.html');
        element(by.buttonText('go')).click();
        element(by.model('myText')).getText().then(function(el) {
            expect(el).toEqual('hoera');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: still get the same result? If I try to bind it to {{myText}} then it works strangely: instead of by.model('myText') using by.binding('myText')

Comment: I can't speak to your locator strategy, as you didn't provide the code, but this will fix your test structure issue. Good luck!